# What use is virt-install to kvm if I have to use virsh? And what use is kvm without configuration?

Tags: memory, configuration, kvm

Based on what I've seen, I can either use kvm to boot from a disk image, or I can use virt-install to create and virsh to run a configured guest, but any way to configure kvm is well hidden by these distractions.  The nice thing about kvm is that I get a console without hacking anything, and on top of that, it's what I'm supposed to be using.  Where do I find configurability that's useful for KVM?  Even something as minimal as RAM size?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the poor, and scattered, manpage(s) for kvm, qemu, etc., I had to wait until I found a practical example to know that there was a -m option to specify the Mb of RAM to qemu-system-x86_64!